# Disable blinking WiFi LED

Tags: wireless, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop constantly blinking Wifi LED?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12069/how-to-stop-constantly-blinking-wifi-led)

I'm trying to disable the blinking WiFi on my HP Elitebook 8530w (Intel WiFi 5300). I've read some articles on the internet and also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12069/how-to-stop-constantly-blinking-wifi-led) question, and they all come to the same solution: add a wlan.conf or iwglan.con, with `options iwlcore led_mode=1` as content in /etc/modprobe.d, and the problem is gone.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, I've tried restarting every time I changed these files, but it still keeps blinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now `iwlwifi`, not `iwlcore`.