# my wifi blinking light

Tags: 14.04

```
(gedit:19011): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I have a hp compaq notebook 6530b and i have ubuntu 14.04 and my wifi keeps blinking. when i save this options iwlcore led_mode=1 i get this message

Comment: Please describe more detailed and more cleanly which options you saved where.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (flashing wifi) on a Dell Inspiron and found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/12082/67335) helped, but I needed to use `iwlegacy` in lieu of `iwlcore`.

Comment: when i options the gedit to put in this options iwl_legacy led_mode=1 thats what it give me this (gedit:19011): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files