# CQ60-210tu Wifi light blinking

Tags: 14.04, atheros, compaq

The wifi is working perfectly fine BUT the wifi light is constantly blinking red then blue. Red meaning that it's off and blue meaning its on. This is very annoying and I was wondering if there is a fix. I am using the atheros chip in the CQ60-210tu. The chip is a AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/wlanled.conf`:

```
options ath9k blink=0
```

followed by rebooting.

[(Src)](https://askubuntu.com/a/169884/208574)